# Can you propagate a Hosta by a root cutting?

Tags: propagation, hosta

I recently purchased my mom a Victory (species) Hosta (so it was free for her), and it got me to wondering if I can propagate a Hosta by a root cutting like rhubarb, and comfrey for when it comes time to dig the plant in the spring (to have a few more).

Answer (score 3):

A standard way to multiply a *mature* hosta is by "division" just like most herbaceous perennials. Dig it up, chop up the root ball into several pieces with a spade, and replant them as separate plants.

Cutting the root ball with a spade or a knife will cause less damage than trying to pull it apart "carefully."

In practice "mature" means the plant has grown so big that a dead region with no growing stems is forming in the middle.

Trying to do this with a small young plant would be more risky.

The old leaves may die when you do this (in fact some people suggest cutting off all the old leaves when you split the root ball) but new leaves should soon grow from the roots.

Comment: no mention of root cutting propagation

Comment: division is a common term, while it may not be the exact technique you are asking about it is the most common and easy means to create new hosta plants for the regular gardener.  it is quick and efficient.  i also have to add that since you mentioned rhubarb and comfrey that division is the same method i use to propagate those plants.